# Segmentation fault when logging using spdlog in an app that includes another spdlog

Tags: android, c++, native, spdlog

I have a native library that uses `spdlog` for internal logging.

The library is compiled as shared library and the results `.so` files are then used in an Android project which has its own JNI and native c++ code which also uses `spdlog`.

The first time a call to `spdlog` is made, we experience a `SIGSEGV` from it. After some research we found that since `spdlog` is a header-only library it may cause issues when using it this way, so we changed to using it as a static library inside the native library.

This seems to solve the issue but now we get the `SIGSEGV` on the first call to `spdlog` from the application's native code.

Are there any limitations or issues with using `spdlog` this way, specifically in an Android project?
Any suggestions on debugging the issue?

If any code can be helpful, let me know what is needed and I'll update the question

**Edit**

Also, it's worth noting that it only happens when the native library is built in Release mode. In Debug everything works as expected

Comment: *so we changed to using it as a static library inside the native library.* -- Did `spdlog` have instructions on doing this, or did you do this on your own?  If you did this on your own, you are taking the risk of using `spdlog` in an untested fashion.  I bet even the spdlog people don't know what results you may get.

Comment: `spdlog` is available as a static library for a long time now. (~2019) see here https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/120 and the readme here https://github.com/gabime/spdlog#static-lib-version-recommended---much-faster-compile-times so it is a well tested option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the solution was just to upgrade to a newer version of `spdlog`

Comment: I'm having similar issues. Two libraries using spd log and seg fault when one of them gets destructed. Which version are you using?